# multi thread launch arrangement

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have 2 thread to create thread1 and thread2. When creating threads with:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &function_th1, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &function_th2, NULL);
```

The thread2 is launched before the thread1 and I'm looking for a solution to start thread1 before thread2.

Not looking for this solution:

```
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &function_th2, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &function_th1, NULL);
```

Comment: Can you post more background as to why you want thread1 to be launched before thread2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here after the solution I suggest

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static bool wait = TRUE;

void thread_sync() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
  wait = FALSE;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}
void thread_wait_sync() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
  if (wait==TRUE)
  {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mut);
  }
  wait = TRUE;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

void *thread1(void *d) {
  thread_sync();
  while (1); // Rest of work happens whenever
  return NULL;
}

void *thread2(void *d) {
  thread_sync();
  while (1);
  return NULL;
}

void *thread3(void *d) {
  thread_sync();
  while (1);
  return NULL;
}

void *thread4(void *d) {
  while (1);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4;
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
  thread_wait_sync();
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);
  thread_wait_sync();
  pthread_create(&t3, NULL, thread3, NULL);
  thread_wait_sync();
  pthread_create(&t4, NULL, thread4, NULL);
  while(1) {
    // some work
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get this code. You are doing `broadcast` and `signal` but nobody is waiting?

Comment: This code uses condition variables incorrectly. If `pthread_cond_signal` is invoked when the main thread is not waiting, nothing happens and your code will deadlock, waiting for a signal that will never arrive. A flag is required in addition; see the answer from Tudor for an example.

Comment: That's true. I added a boolean variable to avoid waiting in case if the pthread_cond_signal is invoked before pthread_cond_wait. Code updated

Answer (score 5):

There is no relation between when a thread creation call is issued and when the thread actually starts executing. It all depends on implementation, OS, etc. that's why you are seeing the two threads actually starting in a seemingly random order.

If you need thread 1 to start before thread 2 you probably have some data/logical dependency on some event. In this case you should use a condition variable to tell thread 2 when to actually begin executing.

```
// condition variable
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
// associated mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// state for condition variable
int shouldWait = 1;

...

void* function_th1(void* p) {
     // execute something

     // signal thread 2 to proceed
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     shouldWait = 0;
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

     // other stuff
}

void* function_th2(void* p) {
     // wait for signal from thread 1
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     while(shouldWait) {
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
     }
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

     // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Also use synchronization while checking or setting that condition. Mutex will do in this case.

Comment: +1, especially for correctly locking while changing the condition and signalling, which I've seen many people forget.

Comment: @Tudor, Right, but I commented before you posted the code )))

Comment: @superM: Yes I know, I just mentioned in case you have other comments to the code. :)

Comment: What's wrong with the simple solution of just creating thread 2 from thread 1?

Answer (score 3):

Move the 'pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &function_th2, NULL);' to the top of the 'function_th1' function.

That will certainly achieve what you ask for, no complex signalling required.

Whether what you ask for is what you actually want or need is another matter.

Comment: Hmm... since I don't see any state being passed around this could be a great idea!

Comment: @Tudor Your solution is good, I already thought that I can run my thread with priority. Is that such a solution exists on Linux? because I developed a multithread application.

Comment: @Ahmed ZRIBI: You can set priorities for pthreads, but that won't solve your problem. It will not guarantee that thread 1 gets to run before thread 2.

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI - then, as we suspected, what you actually want or need is not what you asked for.  Obviously, if thread 2 is created by thread 1, it is absolutely guaranteed that thread 1 will run first, ie. what you asked for.  Can you be more clear about what you actually want and why?

Comment: @Martin James: I have several threads that starts one after another and operate on a single linked list that contains a set of action to have the order to launch these threads is very important.

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI, as I posted before also, if you could provide your complete problem statement, people here will be able to help you better.

Comment: "I have several threads that starts one after another and operate on a single linked list that contains a set of action" - Looks similar to race conditions to me. Can't it be solved by using mutexes or condition variables which control access to the linked list itself rather than controlling the order of scheduling of threads? Anyways, unless you post more info, not much can be done. : )