# I can not get three threads to be in order

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have a three threads that I would like to serialize
I am using pthreads is C++. I am trying to order the output so that it will be {A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,...............}. I am doing this because I have so many threads that I would like to serialize.
the output that I would like to have is:

```
Thread A
Thread B
Thread C
Thread A
Thread B
Thread C
Thread A
Thread B
Thread C
Thread A
Thread B
Thread C
........
........
```

This is the code that I am having. It hangs sometimes and sometime run for one or two loops and then hangs. I would like to hear what you think the problem.
My code is:
thread_test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int condition = 0;
int count = 0;

void* thread_c( void * arg )
{
   while( 1 )
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
      while( condition != 2 )
         pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );
      printf( "Thread C");
      condition = 0;
      pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
   }

   return( 0 );
}

void* thread_b( void * arg )
{
   while( 1 )
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
      while( condition != 1 )
         pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );
      printf( "Thread B" );
      condition = 2;
      pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
   }

   return( 0 );
}

void*  thread_a( void * arg )
{
   while( 1 )
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
      while( condition != 0 )
         pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );
      printf( "Thread A");
      condition = 1;
      pthread_cond_signal( &cond );      
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
   }
   return( 0 );
}

int main( void )
{
    pthread_t  thread_a_id;
    pthread_create( &thread_a_id, NULL, &thread_a, NULL );
    pthread_t  thread_b_id;
    pthread_create( &thread_b_id, NULL, &thread_b, NULL );
    pthread_t  thread_c_id;
    pthread_create( &thread_c_id, NULL, &thread_c, NULL );
    int a = pthread_join(thread_a_id, NULL);
    int b = pthread_join(thread_b_id, NULL);
    int c = pthread_join(thread_c_id, NULL);
}
```

To compile the code, I use

```
g++ -lpthread -std=gnu++0x thread_test.cpp
```

Comment: 'I have a three threads that I would like to serialize' - why?

Comment: I have much more than three threads. I have a control thread that is controlling all these threads. I am using kernel signals to synchronize all of them. The problem is that kernel signals are slow and not efficient to use with threads. So I am trying to use this new method.

Comment: the following question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616787/multithread-launching-order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is that `pthread_cond_signal()` is free to pick whichever waiting thread it wishes, whereas your code depends on it picking a specific thread.

If I replace `pthread_cond_signal()` with `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, I can no longer get the code to stall. I am mentioning this as an observation; I am yet to convince myself that this is a correct fix.

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the question of why you want to serialize the threads to this extent, the problem is that if more than one thread is waiting on the condition, `pthread_cond_signal( &cond )` may only wake up one of them to check the condition (actually that's the intended and usually desired behavior - it's more of an accident if more then one waiter is released).

For example, when `thread_a()` sets `condition = 1` it is intending to wake up `thread_b`.  However, `thread_c` may be waiting at the same time as `thread_b`.  Using `pthread_cond_signal` you have no control over which of `thread_b` or `thread_c` will be released.

Use `pthread_cond_broadcast( &cond )` instead to wake all waiters.

Answer (score 0):

Three condition variables, one for each thread. Thread A signals the one thread B is waiting form who signals the one thread C waits for, who signals the one thread A is waiting for...

However, what's the use of having three threads that can work in parallel, if you are only going to run them serially?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this: [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.