# can we use "goto" keyword to end a thread?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, goto

In many programming languages, many questions have been raised to stop execution of a `thread`.In  `c/c++`  `goto` is still used, where as in `Java` , goto is not used,but still it's reserved; stop(), stop(Throwable) and suspend(), destroy() and resume(), which were intended to provide the basic functionality for starting and stopping a thread  has  been depreciated.
Can we use `goto` to simply to move out of a thread?

Somethig like this :

```
//Thread block

{...
 if(some condition)
goto out;
.....
 ...
 }//thread block over

out:
// I am out!!
}
```

I know using `goto` is a very very bad practice, but can still it be used like this?

**UPDATE:**

Or:

```
//Thread block

{...
 if(some condition)
goto out;
.....
 ...
 out:
 // I am out!!
 }//thread block over
```

From the comments,is this the solution?

**UPDATE2:**

Well,I am getting  mix kind of answers.Some yes,some no.I don't use c/c++ much ,otherwise could have implemented and see myself.

Comment: what is a thread block? at least in c++ and c, threads are not part of the core language, that is you need some kind of functor execute things in a thread.

Comment: If you could do that it would not exit the thread but keep running at the new location probably leading to a crash.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: In C++11 threads are part of the core language. Of course you still can't exit them with a goto. ;)

Comment: There is a difference between program flow control and thread context.

Comment: @Skalli: how do you start a thread in c++11 with only core language facilities?

Comment: In C++ you "can" almost everything, but "should not" most of time (because this may not work as you expect it to work).

Comment: @Skalli: They are part of the standard library, not the language core.

Comment: @Grizzly are you talking about pthreads or something like that?
well,refering to comments and answers, still i am confused,yes or no?

Comment: Why is this question flagged as several different languages?  What language are you using exactly?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Well, at least some parts of threading like memory model or thread local storage are part of the core. The thread classes are part of the STL, that's right.

Comment: @Ramhound common languages which use goto, i use java,cannot implement goto.

Comment: @joeyrohan: I'm talking about `std::thread`, which is a new addition in c++11 (though almost identical functionality is availible in boost).

Comment: So if you know Java cannot implement `goto` why is this question flagged as Java?  Its also flagged as C# yet you don't even mention it.  I am trying to figure out what the tags should be so the correct people who can answer your question will see it.  This clearly has NOTHING to do with C# at this point.

Comment: @Ramhound its general question to different programming languages,where the scope of goto may vary

Comment: @joeyrohan - So basically this is a http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ question?

Comment: no, a question which may have different answeres

Comment: @joeyrohan - This question could be modified to fit with programmers.stackexchange.com currently its just seems very ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "move out" of a thread using goto. A thread's execution is not limited to a given scope and just moving to another location in your code will not terminate it.

Comment: yeah,true +1.Nice  direct answer.Well,if the program exits,will the thread still be running?

Comment: The answer to this question is a bit long. If the *main thread has ended*, the program will not exit until all the other threads are done, unless you have explicitly created a `daemon thread`. Here I say if the main thread has ended as I guess that is what you are asking for - of course if the program exits everything associated with it is dead including all threads.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't work.

1. You can't `goto` to another method.
2. A thread is not bound to a method and one method can be executed by multiple threads.

If the `goto` location would be in the same method, the execution would simply continue at the new location in the thread that executed the `goto` statement.

What you *can* do, is go to the end of the thread method - if the current code is in that method. This won't end the thread, but the `goto` will move the program flow just before the end of the thread method which will lead to the thread method being finished executing and thus ending the thread.
This is the same effect as simply `return`ing from the thread method.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, you *can*: you can use `goto` to transfer control unconditionally to the end of your method from almost anywhere, with very few restrictions. If this is the method that implements your thread, it will exit, ending the thread.

Whether you *should* is a different question: with very few exceptions, `goto` makes your program less readable; without exceptions, you can achieve the same result without a `goto`, and improve readability at the same time. For example, you could use `return` to end the method implementing the logic of your thread.

Comment: Yeah.. that's what I would have thought.  All code is run by threads, so exiting a thread block by jumping to the end seems, well, 'normal'.  There may be private resources to be freed at the end, but with appropriate care, why not GOTO EXIT?

Comment: @MartinJames Java and C# provide nice support for cases like that with the `finally` keyword, while in C++ and C a `goto` is an OK choice to deal with resource cleanup at the end of the function.

Comment: Oh sure, if I have 'finally', then yes.  If I had all that stuff, I would probably raise an exception to get out from some inner method.  Plain C is just painful now :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `goto` might be an ok choice for cleanup in C, but I would strongly disagree with it being one for C++ (except maybe for some embedded platforms, which probably don't completely support C++ anyways). Afterall isn't that what we have RAII for?

Comment: @Grizzly I think that RAII helps your code manage cleanups in the presence of unexpected jumps - exceptions, premature returns, and, yes - `goto`s. I would discourage use of `goto` in C++, but not outright ban it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Is this answer in contradiction with the first one?

Comment: @joeyrohan No, I think the first part of the top answer was done before your first edit, and assumed that you wanted to jump to a different function. The second part says essentially the same thing that I'm saying, with more technicalities about ending the thread (i.e. explaining that `goto` does not end the thread; it's the end of the method that does).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ` goto to transfer control unconditionally to the end of your method from almost anywhere ` what can be the scope of almost anywhere?

Comment: @joeyrohan "almost anywhere" needs to be inside your method, of course, because otherwise the label will be out of scope. I said "almost" because you cannot jump forward over a variable that’s initialized in the same block as the `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, putting cleanup code at end of function, and jumping to it with `goto` is quite valid pattern in C. Use it when ever it *makes the code cleaner and easier to understand*. Of course it can be abused, and it doesn't work that well when you have multiple levels of functions, so it might encourage making too long functions just to be able to goto to cleanup code. But as long as it's used carefully, `goto` is quite valid in C. Also, since the question is a bit vague, better say this explicitly: you can not `goto` between functions. And in languages supporting exceptions, you should use those instead of `goto` (of course you have to use them right too, not abuse them).

But often, especially with threads, it is better to register cleanup handlers for the thread, so you can then just return or call the thread frameworks "exit this thread" function, instead of using `goto` to cleanup code.

Finally, with the code above, with no code after `out:` label, you could just `return` instead of using `goto`... This assumes you are using a threading library, which takes a function to run in other thread, and will end the thread when that function returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can not goto to a label out of the your thread function

You can set the `out:` at the end of the thread  functio. And in this way if you want to stop your thread you can `goto` the `out:` (from any place in your thread function) and the thread function will be stopped

If you want to execute some part of your code at the end of your thread you can use `pthread_cond_signal(&cond);`

the following link contains an example of how to use it: [multithread launching order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616787/multithread-launching-order)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

But perhaps you don't need to... You can try to use ThreadAbortException (by calling Thread.Abort()) and catch it (yes, within the thread), executing the 'out' functionality, and do a Thread.ResetAbort. Just be careful and be sure to read up on the risks involved on MSDN when calling abort from another thread (which you don't seem to be doing).

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx